How to return a default object instead of `None` for an optional relationship in SQLAlchemy?
I have a users table and a roles table, such that a User optionally has a single Role:
class User(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    role: Mapped[Optional["Role"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    # ...


class Role(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"))

    user: Mapped[Optional["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="role")
    # ...

Now in code I would like that User.role always return a Role. If a specific User doesn't have a Role, it should just return a new default one: Role().
How can I replace User.role with some kind of getter function that does this?

A somewhat obvious solution would be:
class User(Base):
    # ...
    @property
    def role_or_new():
        return self.role or Role()

However, I kind of want to override the default attribute name, role.

There are some similarly named existing questions, but I think they're all subtly different:

Flask-SQLAlchemy set relationship default value: solved through events
How to set a default value for a relationship in SQLAlchemy?: Adds a new method, but I want to modify how the existing attribute role behaves
How to set a default value from a SQLAlchemy relationship?: Asks how to get default values based of an existing relationship


Why not simply flip the workaround property definition in the other direction? Just have relationship(back_populates="_role") defined for class Role and _role: Mapped... defined for class User and then now you can have @property on def role. A "native sqlalchemy" solution may be possible if you were to override the underlying RelationshipProperty and modify its usage of the descriptor protocol, or solve it through events by injecting the dummy Role() into users with its role as None.

Thanks for the suggestion, that seems to work well. If you don't feel like it, I'll add it as an answer later with my own implementation.

Please go ahead with a self-answer.

Following @metatoaser's hint, I renamed the relationship from the user and created a property with the original name for compatibility:
class User(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    role_row: Mapped[Optional["Role"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    # ...

    @property
    def role() -> Role:
        if self.role_row is None:
            self.role_row = Role()
            # Consider using `make_transient(self.role_row)` here
        return self.role_row


class Role(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"))

    user: Mapped[Optional["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="role_row")
    # ...

Mind that the back_populates= of the Role model is now different too.
I opted for a public property, role_row, such an advanced user could still choose to use the original relationship, which would be discouraged with a name like _role.
Final note: the newly created Role() will be queued in the session by default! E.g.:
user = session.get(User, 1)
if user.role.access:
    # ...

user.email = new_email
session.commit()

...will trigger the creation of a new Role in the database! This is because every created object by default corresponds to a database row.
If you want to prevent this default object from always appearing in the database on the next commit, you could add a call to make_transient in the custom getter.

Simple and easy, I would go same way..
